# password authentication offline and online within android app

Tags: android, password-protection

I have a requirement for an app to authenticate before access is allowed.

However, there is also a need for it to be secure when not online or the remote login/authentication server cannot be found.

What's the best way to achieve an offline username/password policy. Nothing has been written yet so any security approach, e.g. oauth2, hash+salt, is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK oauth2 offline is not possible as you will need an oauth server to communicate to. Anyway, your implementation may be relative to the information you are trying to protect; if you're storing simple user preferences and trivial data, yeah you can hash + salt, otherwise you can go over bcrypt http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: It cannot be 100% secure. If you have auth data on the client it can be altered.

Answer (score 0):

Store the username and password **hash** on the phone itself. If offline, check against local data source. Else check online.

This is basically what Windows does when you normally authenticate with a remote domain server, but still lets you authenticate if offline.

You might want to force the user to have a phone swipe login, like required when you use a VPN.

You cannot fully protect your app of course. As a user has physical access to the phone, they own everything on it. Get root, run a debugger, and own your app. This is unavoidable.